# How to create a useful ECO list?

Tags: scid, eco

I am using SCID; the built-in ECO list is very incomplete and sometimes just weird. The *Caro-Kann: Accelerated Panov Attack* for example is called *Caro-Kann: English Variation*, the *Carls-Botvinnik Defense* hasn't even a name, and many sub-variations are just missing.

So I want to build my own list to use it in SCID.

I like the [lichess opening list](https://github.com/ornicar/scalachess/blob/7e65fa3beb00fa5f4ff3bafce48dd35835d61f44/src/main/scala/opening/FullOpeningPart1.scala), but it is based on FEN positions, not on moves, and SCID needs the latter. I looked at the related questions here, and searched on Google, but couldn't find a good text file with moves and correct opening names.

How should I proceed? Maybe there is already such a file and I just haven't found it, or I can use FEN positions in SCID instead of moves?

Answer (score 1):

I maintain one here that you might like to take a look at to see if it is any use for your purposes:

[PGN for ECO descriptions with moves](ftp://ftp.cs.kent.ac.uk/pub/djb/pgn-extract/eco.pgn)

Comment: Hmm, yes, thanks, that's at least something. But the _Accelerated Panov_ is called _anti-Caro-Kann defence_, that specifically is one of my pet bugs in the TWIC files. :) There are other issues, like giving the _Masi variation_ its own main opening name _Caro-Masi_ … I'd rather have something that I don't have to check line by line; there are just too many named lines.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this list, but I'm not sure how well it matches your naming convention: [http://cricketchess.pcriot.com/opg/](http://cricketchess.pcriot.com/opg/index.php)

As a programmer, I can tell you it is very difficult to match an opening to PGN but much easier to match it to a FEN. In the case of the Caro-Kann, Accelerated Panov (and other openings as well), it is worthy to note that the opening goes by other names: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caro-Kann_Defence#Other_lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caro%E2%80%93Kann_Defence#Other_lines)
 (B10, Modern; English Variation, Accelerated Panov: 1.e4 c6 2.c4).

I found that opening also called "Caro-Kann, Anti-Caro-Kann" for instance in my Android app.